# iMacro Firefox get CSS background url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Firefox addon - iMacro

```
ATTR=ONCLICK:startlink*&&CLASS:cursor<SP>earn_pages_button*&&TXT:
```

This code above look for button with earn_pages_button, however I want to able to avoid clicking links that contain the following background url in its css.

This css is contain in the link, when I inspect element I can see that it contain the following, I would like to skip it

```
background-image: url("http://www.example.com/img/icon/check-not-okay.png");
```

If It is this, I will let it proceed as normal.

```
background-image: url("http://www.example.com/img/icon/check-okay.png");
```

How can I edit my code above to make it working to avoid check-not-okay.png as a valid link to open.

Thanks, the code is written in .iim extension.